# Autogenerating unnapply for play form handling in scala3 for single-element case classes

Tags: scala, playframework, metaprogramming

Scala 3 changed the signature of the auto-generated `unapply` method of case classes ([see here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-other-changes.html#explicit-call-to-unapply)). Unfortunately the `unapply` method is explicitly called when mapping forms for the play framework.

```scala
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class Thing(x: String, y: Int)

val f = Form(mapping(
  "x" -> nonEmptyText(),
  "y" -> number(),
)(Thing.apply)(Thing.unapply))
```

This snippet works in Scala2, but not in Scala3. The [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/ScalaForms#Defining-a-form) recommends to manually define a compatible `unapply` method, but i think we can do better.

And indeed, we can auto-generate the `unapply` method like this:

```scala
# Scala3 only
import scala.deriving.Mirror

object FormHelper:
    def unapply[A <: Product](value: A)(using mirror: Mirror.ProductOf[A]): Option[mirror.MirroredElemTypes] =
        Some(Tuple.fromProductTyped(value))
```

Defining forms now looks like this:

```scala
# Scala3 only

val f = Form(mapping(
  "x" -> nonEmptyText(),
  "y" -> number(),
)(Thing.apply)(FormHelper.unapply))
```

But now the problems begin. Given a case class with a single member:

```scala
case class Single(x: String)
```

My `FormHelper.unapply` returns an option of a tuple with a single element, like `Option[Tuple1[T]]`. But for some reasons the `mapping` function for play needs a flat `Option[T]`.

So my question is: how can i extend my `FormHelper` (either with a new method, or extend the existing `unapply`) such that it returns `Option[T]` when given a case class with a single member.

The closest i could get to that was this

```
def single[A <: Product](value: A)(using mirror: Mirror.ProductOf[A]) = Some(Tuple.fromProductTyped(value).take(1))
```

The return type of that is `Some[T *: EmptyTuple]` and i'm not able to get rid of the `EmptyTuple` thing.

My guess is, that i somehow need to restrict the method to products of length 1, but unfortunately case classes only inherit from `Product` and not the specific `ProductN[T...]` traits.

Note: i know that i could use this to make the form definition work:

```scala
val f = Form(mapping(
  "x" -> nonEmptyText(),
)(Single.apply)(t => Some(t._1))
```

but i'm also interested how to do that with the meta-programming approach.

Comment: If you are already using Scala 3 with `Mirror`s I guess it would make sense to, IDK, create a typeclass which would generate `apply` and `unapply` out of mirror and had a special case in derivation for 1-element tuples?